# find and replace tags with different name with regex in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I works on a xml file and i open it in vscode.
now i want to find tags and change.
i dont know how to find these tags <same{anithings}> in vscode search box
every regex that i tested is not working.
pleade help, tnx

```
<same1></same1>
<same2></same2>

to

<same></same>
<same></same>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to search for:

```
<(/?)same\w+>
```

Comment: Wow. i enable regex mode and it working. tnx

Answer (score 1):

Search for

```
<same(\w+)></same\1>
```

You want the anything parts to match